# Multiplicative Functions and Totient Function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, multiplicative-function

I have two questions.

1. If $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function defined on the positive integers, is

$g(n)=\frac{f(n)}{n}$ multiplicative as well?

I think the answer is yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

2. Evaluate
   $$\sum_{d\mid2016} \frac{\phi(d)}{d}$$

where $\phi(n)$ is the totient function.

Comment: The product of two multiplicative functions is multiplicative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards the second question, note that 
$$g(n):=\sum_{d|n} \frac{\phi(d)}{d}$$
is multiplicative (it is the [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) of two multiplicative functions).

Moreover, $n=2016=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot 7$, and for any prime $p$,
$$g(p^k)=\sum_{d|p^k} \frac{\phi(d)}{d}=1+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{p^j-p^{j-1}}{p^j}=1+k\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$
Hence
$$g(2016)=g(2^5)\cdot g(3^2)\cdot g(7)=\frac{7}{2}\cdot\frac{7}{3}\cdot \frac{13}{7}=\frac{91}{6}.$$

Comment: That helps a lot. I'm getting 323/42 with that formula.

Comment: It should be 91/6. Check your computations.

Answer (score 1):

1) Show that for positive integers $m,n$, one has $g(mn) =g (n)g(m) $. Note this is precisely the definition of a function being 'multiplicative.'

2) We have $d$ as any divisor of 2016. Now observe that $2016=2^5×3^2×7$.

Use the fact that the Euler Totient function is multiplicative for coprime numbers to simplify your counting process.

Comment: That's the part I'm confused about. How do I separate this sum in such a way that I can "cleanly" solve it utilizing the multiplicative functions you discuss. I do realize that Euler's totient function is multiplicative when the numbers are relatively prime, but I'm still confused.

Comment: You should have g(mn) = f(mn)/mn. Then because f is multiplicative by assumption, write f (mn)  =f(n)f(m). Can you see it now?

Comment: I understand the first question. What I'm confused by is the second one with the sum.

Comment: Let us see an e.g. Note that 63 is a divisor of 2016. So one of the terms in the summand is phi(63)/63. But 63 = 7×9 and gcd(7,9) =1. So we can write phi(63) = phi(7)phi (9) which is v easy to compute.